# Problem with next-auth. [CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] and 400 bad request

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have a problem, in console I getting this errrors:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session 400 (Bad Request)
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error Unexpected token 'E', "Error: Thi"... is not valid JSON {error: {…}, url: '/api/auth/session', message: `Unexpected token 'E', "Error: Thi"... is not valid JSON`}
POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/_log 400 (Bad Request)
```

I don't know what to do to get rid of this error.

Comment: I have the same problem only on production - Claudflare server.
Did you find solution for this error ? 
[...nextauth].ts is on the right place, working great on local.

Answer (score 2):

it's because the next-js can't find the route **/api/auth**.

 I suppose you have something like

> **"\src\app\api\[...nextauth]\route.js"**

So make sure that you have created the folder **auth** inside the **api** folder like this:

> **"\src\app\api\auth\[...nextauth]\route.js"**